# Search multidimensional array for value in certain key, return value of different key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to php and have been using the community and answers here to really help me with a little project I'm working on so thank you all in advance for the help so far!

I am pulling a load of information held in a poorly formatted text file/feed, trimming the contents of special characters and then using `str_replace` to find other specific strings and replace them with commas(,) or semi-colons(;), in order to create a usable piece of text. I then want to search this text for certain keywords and return other parts of the text in it's place.

So far, I've managed to explode the text into a multidimensional array, but I can't work out how to search this array now, in order to pull out a specific piece of information. I'm essentially trying to build a searchable array that I can pull information from as and when the original feed updates. Here's a sample of the array as it stands at the moment:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 240
        [1] => 1
        [2] => euro
        [3] => 2016-02-19 15:30:00
        [4] => EUR
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 240
        [1] => 3
        [2] => euro2
        [3] => 2016-02-19 15:00:00
        [4] => EUR
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1890
        [1] => 9
        [2] => uspb
        [3] => 2016-02-17 22:59:00
        [4] => USD
    )
)
```

Essentially, I want to be able to write something that will search this array for say `uspb` **(array 2, key 2)** and if it is found, return the value held under another key. So if I want key 0, it will return `1890`. If I want key 1 when searching for `euro2` it will return "3".

I've looked through a ton of examples and nothing really fits what I'm after at the moment. Perhaps I'm looking at this the wrong way and using an array isn't the correct approach. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here's a copy of my code (slight redacted) so far.

```
<?php 
    $file=file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/feed/");
    $trim=trim($file, "[]");
    $find = array("{\"value\":\"", "\",\"date_utc\":\"", "\",\"currency\":\"");
    $replace = array(",", ",", "");
    $replaced = str_replace($find, $replace, $trim);

$ret = array_map (
  function ($_) {return explode (',', $_);},
  explode (';', $replaced)
);

print_r ($ret);
    ?>
```

Comment: `print_r(json_decode($file, true));`

Comment: Just a thought.. are you trying to parse a JSON file? If so you might want to look at some JSON handlers for PHP, like json_decode (http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php). That could make it much easier for you to deal with.

Comment: @whiskeyfur - thanks, didn't know the format of the feed. Perhaps it's time to read up on JSON as I could probably search the data more efficiently.

Comment: You might find one of these PHP array functions helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your array is multidimensional - you have to iterate over it to find the value you need:

```
foreach ($ret as $value) {
    // the index you want to search is always `2`?
    if ($value[2] == 'uspb2') {
        echo $value[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

And moving to function:

```
function findMyValue(
    $array, 
    $search_key,
    $search_str, 
    $key
) {
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if ($v[$search_key] == $search_str) {
            return $v[$key];
        }
    }
    return 'NOT_FOUND';
}

echo findMyValue($ret, 2, 'euro', 1); // outputs 3
echo findMyValue($ret, 2, 'uspb', 0); // outputs 1890
```

And as already noticed in comments - it's not a poorly formated text, it's JSON. You can get an array from JSON string simply with `json_decode` function:

```
$file=file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/feed/");
$ret = json_decode($file, true);
var_dump($ret);
```

Comment: That's brilliant... thank you so much! I can now build a simple search form based on the various entries in each index 2 for the whole set of data.